# Swift: Unexpectedly found "nil" when trying to change property of objects in a function called from another swift file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

So, on my Storyboard I have an UIViewController with a Container View which it has an UITableViewController as embed. That's how it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/or2eY.png

But now I want to set a picture taken by the camera, but the problem is: The UIImageView is inside the UITableViewController and the button for opening the camera is inside the UIViewController (you can see the camera icon on the screenshot I uploaded).

So, I tried this:

Code for the UIViewController:

```
@IBAction func openCamera(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let image = UIImagePickerController()
    image.delegate = self

    image.sourceType = UIImagePickerController.SourceType.camera
    image.allowsEditing = false

    self.present(image, animated: true)
    {

    }
}
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
{

    let info = convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(info)

    if let image = info[convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage)] as? UIImage
    {
        takenPhoto = image //takenPhoto is a global variable
        let CIV = CreateIssue()
        CIV.showImage()
    }
    else
    {

    }

    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
fileprivate func convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKeyDictionary(_ input: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) -> [String: Any] {
    return Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: input.map {key, value in (key.rawValue, value)})
}


fileprivate func convertFromUIImagePickerControllerInfoKey(_ input: UIImagePickerController.InfoKey) -> String {
    return input.rawValue
}
}
```

Code for the UITableViewController:

```
public func showPicture() {
  ivPicture.isHidden = false //here I get Unexpectedly found nil after taking a picture from the camera
  ivPicture.image = takenPhoto
}
```

However, if I try to call the function in the ViewDidLoad, it works fine:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  showPicture()
}
```

The last few days, I posted a similar issue but I was trying to change a variable from another swift file through segues, and I was told to use the prepare for segue method but in this case I am just calling a function of another swift file and the obejcts belong to the same swift file. Would I need to use the prepare for segue method, too? Or what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You create an instance of the child vc

```
let CIV = CreateIssue()
CIV.showImage()
```

that not loaded from storyboard so all outlets are nil , so replace this

```
let CIV = CreateIssue()
```

with

```
let CIV =  self.children[0] as! CreateIssue
```

Comment: @AdriánT95  While this seems to fix your issue, it is a volatile fix which can possibly backfire. Instead of grabbing your `CreateIssue` from `children` and force casting it (never a good idea), you should rather keep a reference to it when you first create it (or add an outlet if it is set in storyboard/xib). It’s hard to tell more without seeing more of your code.

Comment: @Losiowaty if you understands **!** correctly you hadn't say that , it will never crash only if he changes the structure in storyboard which is similar to case that he has an outlet , so please don't stupidly think always that **!** will cause a crash

Comment: I never said that using `!` will always crash, I only said that it is not a good idea. Using `if let` is a safer way to achieve the same. And while I agree that it should not crash unless the storyboard is not changed, I do believe that code should be as resilient as possible. What if another embedded VC is added? Can you then guarantee the order of them in `children` array? Can you guarantee it won’t change with next version of iOS?

Comment: @Losiowaty the developer isn't tipsy he should be aware of all changes and their impact to the current version

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind - A UIView, Tabbleview, and it's cells are all different classes / objects.  They don't have any natural relation between one another even though they appear on the same user interface.  A button in a tableview cell is a member of that Cell's class rather than the Table or the View which contains that Table.

One question - do you need to have this button in a Tableview cell or can it simply exist as part of your UIView?  It's unclear from your example if you need to repeat these cells / have multiple instances of them (the typically UITableViewCell use case) or if a single cell is all you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but I already fixed the issue. Well, I was not changing an object from a UIViewController. I mean, the objects I am trying to change belongs to the UITableViewController and I was trying to change them from the same swift file in a function and this function is called from the UIViewController.

And I do need to have this button in the UIViewController because it is fixed in the top of the screen.